# Storing a anonymous function in a class variable from __construct

Tags: php, callback, closures, class-variables

I'm working a Thread wrapper class that can take in a function and call that function in a new thread.
This my class so far:

```
public function __construct($cbCallback, $aParameters) {

    $this->cbCallback = $cbCallback;
    $this->aParameters = $aParameters;
    $this->return = false;
}

public function run() {

    if (is_array($this->cbCallback)) {

        $this->return = call_user_func($this->cbCallback, ...($this->aParameters));
    }
    else {

        $this->return = $this->cbCallback(...($this->aParameters));
    }
}
```

And this works using the call_user_func portion when taking in a callback. I would like to overload the class so that it can also take in a closure instead of a callback array. I've run into trouble storing the anonymous function as a class variable: it is always stored as null.

I put some debugging statements in the constructor:

```
echo "Paramater test 1: " . json_encode($cbCallback);
$this->cbCallback = $cbCallback;
echo "Paramater test 2: " . json_encode($cbCallback);
echo "Variable test: " . json_encode($this->cbCallback);
```

This yields the output:

```
Paramater test 1: {}
Paramater test 2: {}
Variable test: null
```

I have also tried making `$cbCallback` pass by reference with `&$cbCallback`, which just results in a error that the object cannot be passed by reference.

I feel like either there is a special rule with anonymous functions, or something wonky is going on.
Why can't I store the anonymous function into $this->cbCallback? Is there any way to store the anonymous function in a (non static) class variable or something similar that will work the same way when I need to call that function?

P.S. I'm on PHP v5.6

Comment: which version of php are you on? Might be a problem with the newest version of php.

Comment: Not sure, but if it's a problem specifically with 5.6 I can't try it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the code on one of my other servers that is running an older version of php and see if it is an issue with 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally tracked down the issue I was having. It turns out it is an issue with the pthreads library.

The specified code works perfectly so long as you do not extend the `Thread` class.

I found this bug report on php's website:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67506

Then posted it to krakjoe's github:
https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/355

Turns out he had fixed the issue a couple hours before me posting, so to fix this issue, **make sure you are running pthreads v2.0.9+**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute the closure you stored within the object, try assigning it first to a variable, otherwise you might get "Call to undefined method".

Instead of

```
$this->return = $this->cbCallback(...($this->aParameters));
```

Try this

```
$cb = $this->cbCallback;
$this->return = $cb(...($this->aParameters));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.This might be needed later, but $this->cbCallback is null at that point, so even storing into $cb would simply be moving a reference to null into the new variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can store closure or a lambda-function/anonymous-function in a class variable. However, you cannot serialize it because it is not just a simple value, its a function.

Comment: I don't need to serialize it. I just need to store it. I can't store it, otherwise I would not have posted the question. I have no problem that the outputs are simply {}. The problem is the third output is null.

Comment: "Storing it" Means, that you have to serialize it somehow, and later unserialize to load it into memory. Otherwise you would be unable to use the "stored" data later.

Comment: If a function can be stored as $func = function(){}; as per http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php then it doesn't need to be serialized to be stored in a variable assuming that they are indeed unseralizable.